# VNCviewer password error

Tags: vnc, vncviewer, tigervnc

I am attending a course in which the software (cadence) is installed on the university unix server. To have access the following instruction is shared by the course team. I am using a MAC system.

Steps to setup account for MAC users:

1- Open terminal:

```
%ssh -Y <username> @somename.universityname.edu
```

2- Create your session by:

```
%vncserver -geometry 1920x1080
```

3- Make sure to have checked/killed all your previous sessions (keeping one) by:

```
%vncserver -list

%vncserver -kill : 100XX
```

4- Exit from the connection:

```
%exit
```

5- Type: `%ssh –L 150XX:localhost:150XX –N –f –l  <username> somename.universityname.edu` and type your password

6- Go to vncviewer and type: `localhost:150XX`

This was supposed to fire up my VNCviewer and it was working fine until I forgot the password I setup in the 5th step. I tried to remove the password by `rm .vnc/passwd` and later using `vncpasswd`. It shows the following

[image: password changing step]

Further (this time recording my own password) whenever I am trying to type the password (new one, and I have done it multiple times so I am sure there's no extra character) in it still says permission denied.

[image: Permission denied file]

It would be really helpful if I receive your guidance on how to correct this.

Comment: It's asking for your login password (the same as you used in Step 1) - not your VNC password, I think?

Comment: As *steeldriver* says, at this point you need to enter the password of your account on that server, not the VNC password. There is an option to use VNC without password; to do this, run `vncserver -SecurityTypes None` (from https://serverfault.com/a/580859/380923). However, this might be frowned up by the system administrators.

Comment: Thank you steeldriver @berndbausch for helping me with this. It was indeed my account password. Initially it was giving me a connection time out error but after terminating the whole process and trying again, it seems to work now. Thanks!